# How do I install apt on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, authentication

I'm trying to install Google authenticator on Ubuntu.

I tried `sudo apt install libpam-google-authenticator` which results in the error `sudo: apt: command not found`. Shouldn't `apt` already be installed on Ubuntu? I have tried several commands with `apt`. Beware I am very new to Linux.

When I use the command `lsb_release -a` this is the output:

```
-bash: lsb_release: command not found
```

I installed "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" from the Microsoft Store.

When I use the command `cat /etc/os-release` this is the output:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="8"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-8"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8"
```

```
$: echo $PATH
/home/mkristiansen/.local/bin:/home/mkristiansen/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: Yes, it should. Which version of Ubuntu are you running? And could you please add some screenshots of the message?

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the output of the command `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: `apt` is always installed on Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, and every official flavour of Ubuntu.  Can you tell us how it was removed?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in WSL?

Comment: I have only installed ubuntu from microsoft store on my windows 10 computer. I have not installed WSL. Thank you

Comment: Could you update with an output of `cat /etc/os-release` ?

Comment: Also, please show an output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: Your output clearly shows that you are running CentOS, not Ubuntu. CentOS does not use apt.

Comment: 1) Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store in Windows 10 **is** WSL. If you installed any Linux distro on Windows from the Microsoft Store, you are using WSL.  2) You aren't running Ubuntu, you are running CentOS which does not use `apt` as a package manager, it uses `yum` 3) CentOS is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  You can ask about CentOS on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Why is it running centOS when the program I installed is called ubuntu? And how do I run ubuntu is there something else I need to install? Thank you all for taking your time and help.

Comment: Somehow you installed CentOS.  Perhaps you also installed Ubuntu, but when you entered those commands, you weren't using Ubuntu, you were using CentOS.  CentOS is an entirely different Linux distribution and is not very similar to Ubuntu as it is in the "RedHat" family of Linux and Ubuntu is Debian-based.

Comment: Ok I see. Do you have a guide on how to install ubuntu properly?

Comment: @user1560375 Yes. Open the Microsoft Store, click the search bar, and type "Ubuntu". Click on it, and press install. Here is [a link to Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) in the Store. Once you've downloaded it, just launch it (from the start menu), do the short setup, and then enjoy it!

Comment: @user1560375 If you are using the latest Windows 10 (21H2) or Windows 11 release, simply `wsl --install Ubuntu`.  Cocomac's method works also (for all WSL and Windows releases).

Comment: I just wanted to add that I logged in to my schools server with ssh username@server-adress and that might be why it was running on centOS, is it that my schools server somehow runs on centOS? When Im logged in on my PC on ubuntu and write command "cat /etc/os-release" it says ubuntu. So only when I ssh to my schools server and write command "cat /etc/os-release" it says centOS?

Answer (score 3):

You are running CentOS, not Ubuntu. CentOS uses `yum` as package manager.
If, for any reason, you still want to use `apt` on what you're running, [check this out](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/apt-centos).